# Babel 7.5 targeting babel-preset-es2015 instead of @babel/preset-env

Tags: reactjs, babeljs

I have installed babel 7.5 which should ideally target preset-env package but not sure why it is looking for 'babel-preset-es2015'.

Can you guys please suggest me what mistake I did? Below is my code

*package.json*

```
{
  "name": "",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "webpack-dev-server --mode development --open --hot",
    "build": "webpack --mode production"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "^16.9.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.9.0",
    "webpack": "^4.39.2",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.3.7",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.8.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.5.5",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.5.5",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.0.0",
    "babel-loader": "^8.0.6",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^3.2.0"
  }
}
```

*.babelrc*

```
{
    "presets": [
        "@babel/preset-env",
        "@babel/preset-react"
    ]
}
```

#### Below is the error:

Module build failed (from ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js):
Error: Cannot find module 'babel-preset-es2015' from 'D:\Shashank\Projects\UploadUtility'

Answer (score 3):

Hello @Shashank Srivastava,

In the **webpack.config.js** file you have the *module* property

```
module: {
      rules: [
         {
            test: /\.jsx?$/,
            exclude: /node_modules/,
            loader: 'babel-loader',
            query: {
               presets: ['es2015', 'react'] // here is the problem!
            }
         }
      ]
   },
```

I've found that the old terminology of the presets is the problem here.

For babel 7.5+ the correct preset names are **"@babel/preset-env"** and **"@babel/preset-react"** in this particular case.

So the long story short you already have the new correct preset names in the **.babelrc** file so you should update the **webpack.config.js** file with the new preset names:

```
query: {
   presets: ["@babel/preset-env", "@babel/preset-react"] // updated preset names
}
```

It will instruct the babel-loader to look for and load the proper presets.

This solution worked for me so I hope it works for you also.